# How can I add script to Qwik's head?

Tags: qwik

I want to add script to Qwik's `root.tsx` file. I tried:

```
<script>
  const globalFunction = (parameter) => console.log('hi')
</script>
```

But this can not be compiled.

I changed it to become similar to Next.js:

```
<script>
   {
       `const globalFunction = (parameter) => console.log('hi')`
   }
</script>
```

But I saw that the `=>` arrow function is rendered as `=&gt;`

How can I write literal script in Qwik?

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it is using [Context](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/context/)

And another way is to use [Partytown](https://qwik.builder.io/integrations/partytown/)

Third-party scripts or custom script tags substantially slow down your initial page load by blocking the main thread.

Partytown is a tool that allows you to defer third-party scripts like Google Analytics, Facebook Pixel, etc off the main thread by using a web worker. For more information about this tool visit the [Partytown docs](https://partytown.builder.io/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script in separate .tsx file:

```
export const MyScript = () => (
  <script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={`console.log("Hello, Qwik! From MyScript!");`} />
);
```

Then add it to root.tsx into `<head>`, ex:

```
return (
<QwikCityProvider>
  <head>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <RouterHead />
    <MyScript />
  </head>
```